# Oracle: WITH-clause querying two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, with-statement

Using an Oracle database, I have two tables:

```
Employees:

Employee_id | Number(6,0)
Last_name   | Varchar2(20)
Hire_date   | Date
Deparment_id| Number(4,0)

Job_history:

Employee_id  | Number(6,0)
Start_date   | Date
Deparment_id | Number(4,0)
```

I am supposed to find - using the WITH-clause - all the employees who currently work in the same department where they started to work (hire_date = start_date and same department_id). I easily got the right result using a JOIN in the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.hire_date, 
e.department_id as current_dep, j.department_id as prev_dep
FROM hr.employees e 
JOIN (SELECT employee_id, department_id, end_date, start_date 
      FROM hr.job_history ) j
ON e.employee_id = j.employee_id
WHERE e.department_id = j.department_id;
```

(Right) OUTPUT:
[image]

Unfortunately with the WITH-clause I am getting troubles, since I am not sure how to manage two different tables (most examples I found on the web are just with one table)

```
 --best try until now--

With find_emp as (SELECT hire_date, department_id 
                    FROM hr.employees)
SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id as curr_dep
FROM HR.employees e
WHERE e.hire_date IN (SELECT j.start_date
                      FROM hr.job_history j
                      JOIN hr.employees e
                      ON e.employee_id = j.employee_id);
```

(wrong) OUTPUT:
[image]

What I am doing wrong? Since I am new to SQL, I would appreciate every hint. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how the WITH(CTE) works. [Here][1] is a good explanation, please check it first then comeback if you still have any concern.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57610712/when-do-we-use-with-clause-and-what-are-main-benefits-of-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something among the lines:

```
WITH start_dept AS
(
  SELECT emp.employee_id, dept.deparment_id AS prev_dep
    FROM employees   emp
       , job_history dept
   WHERE emp.employee_id = dept.employee_id
     AND emp.hire_date   = dept.start_date
)
SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.hire_date, e.deparment_id AS current_dep, sd.prev_dep
  FROM employees  e
     , start_dept sd
 WHERE e.employee_id  = sd.employee_id
   AND e.deparment_id = sd.prev_dep;
```

(assuming Employees.deparment_id is the current departmen and Employees.hire_date matches the start_date from Job_history)

Answer (score 1):

The SQL WITH clause creates 'virtual' tables which you can reference in later queries under the clause.  These tables exist for the lifetime of the query in memory.  They are a bit like views.

Your example is not working as you are establishing a virtual table called `find_emp`, but then you are not using it.

An example

```
WITH subquery AS (
SELECT col1 , col2, col3 
FROM table1
WHERE col4=condition1
)

SELECT * FROM subquery;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an employee that has the same job that means there will be only one entry in the JOB_HISTORY table for that employee.

Therefore, you can do something like this.

```
CREATE table dept  (department_id, department_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'IT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'MARKETING' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'SALES'  FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE employees (employee_id, first_name, last_name, department_id, sal) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', 'Abbot', 1, 100000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beryl', 'Baron', 1, 50000 FROM DUAL;

CREATE table job_history  (employee_id,
department_id) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3   FROM DUAL;

WITH rws AS
(
  SELECT 
   e.employee_id,
   e.first_name, 
   e.last_name,
   e.department_id,
   d.department_name
 FROM EMPLOYEES e join dept d on e.department_id = d.department_id
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID IN
  (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM JOB_HISTORY GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID  HAVING COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) =1)
)
SELECT 
   employee_id,
   first_name, 
   last_name,
   department_id,
   department_name
 FROM rws;

EMPLOYEE_ID    FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME    DEPARTMENT_ID    DEPARTMENT_NAME
1    Alice    Abbot    1    IT
```